# Using different console for respawn process in inittab on embedded device

Tags: tty, inittab

I am connected on my embedded device with the serial port and would like to start my custom binaries on boot and be able to see the output generated.

My /etc/inittab file contains:

```
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyAPP3 vt100
console::respawn:/usr/bin/mybinary
```

With this configuration, I can see the output of mybinary in the serial console but It is difficult/impossible to connect (insert login and password) to getty because of the interference of the output generated.

I tried to switch the output in inittab to another not used tty (tty10) like this:

```
console::respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyAPP3 vt100
tty10::respawn:/usr/bin/mybinary
```

And now I can connect but how can I see the output generated to /dev/tty10 ?

I tried `cat /dev/tty10` but nothing is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the question is old, but it has no answers at all for crying out loud.

Remember that a TTY is both an output device and also an input device -- by cat'ing from it you're reading *input* from the terminal which means the keyboard, NOT the screen.

I don't know if there's a parallel in other *nixes, but Linux systems have /dev/vcsX and /dev/vcsaX character devices (nodes c,7,0+X and c,7,128+X respectively) for each /dev/ttyX device - these are mirrors of the data currently on the *output* of the TTY device (ie. the screen part of the TTY, not the keyboard part).  These will give you what you're looking for.  The vcsaX devices will give you a displaybyte+attributebyte pair (i.e. the foreground/background text colour -- see other references for more information on text attribute bytes) for each character on the screen, while the vcsX devices give only the displaybyte for each character.  Of course it's a raw stream/dump so if the row and/or column count of your terminal doesn't match that of the the TTY you're dumping then you'll need to parse the data and reformat it to match.

tl;dr: use "cat /dev/vcs10"

Hope that helps.